# Surrounding img with link in flex container causes img to ignore container boundaries

Tags: html, css

I have a page containing rows of images in a flexbox container. I'm attempting to link these images to their source images, and when surrounding the images with an `<a>` tag, the image no longer conforms to the boundaries of its parent container. I realize this is likely because the `<a>` tag becomes the `<img>` tag's parent, but I'm inheriting attributes from the parent container, so the `<a>` tag should be styled the same.

How can I get the image to respect the 350x225 boundary with this setup?

With Link:

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.frame-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.frame-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 225px;
  max-width: 31%;
}

.frame-item a {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.frame-item>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-row">
  <div class="frame-item">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/1000">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000">
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p>Grand Royale Ct.<br> Alamo, CA</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without Link:

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.frame-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.frame-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 225px;
  max-width: 31%;
}

.frame-item a {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.frame-item>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-row">
  <div class="frame-item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000">
    <div class="item-overlay">
      <p>Street<br> City, State</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.frame-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.frame-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 225px;
  max-width: 31%;
}

.frame-item a {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.frame-item a>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-row">
  <div class="frame-item">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/1000">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000">
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p>Grand Royale Ct.<br> Alamo, CA</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell us what did you change/add, It's hard to play at  *find the difference*

Comment: @Temani Afif - he changed the selector for images since image is no longer a direct descendant of .frame-item

Comment: @froggomad I know what he changed, I meant it's useful to say this in the answer so people who don't understand the issue can easily find this because it's no something trivial to notice